Problems with context when updating an array
I'm encountering an issue with the state of my context when updating a state that is an array. Specifically, I have an object that stores days selected by the user, which can be removed one by one. When removing a day, the React state does not update, and the useEffect hook is not executed.
dates in type
remove a date
remove date again
here is my code :
    import { createContext, Dispatch, useContext, useEffect, useReducer } from "react";

// mock/after-school.ts
export const GetDailyServicesResponse = {
  "serviceId": 116,
  "name": "After school",
  "description": "After school",
  "bookingId": 62,
  "bookingServiceId": 82,
  "bookingCalendarId": 22,
  "services": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "first service",
      "value": 23200,
      "lunch": 0,
      "ticket": 1
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "second service",
      "value": 29200,
      "lunch": 1,
      "ticket": 1
    },
    {
      "id": 3,
      "name": "third service",
      "value": 6000,
      "lunch": 1,
      "ticket": 0
    }
  ]
}

export const MockDates = [
  new Date("11-02-2024"),
  new Date("11-03-2024"),
  new Date("11-04-2024"),
  new Date("11-05-2024"),
  new Date("11-06-2024"),
  new Date("11-07-2024"),
  new Date("11-08-2024"),
  new Date("11-09-2024"),
  new Date("11-10-2024"),
  new Date("11-11-2024"),
]
//utils/date.ts
export const formatDayMonth = (value: string, symbol: string) => {
  const date = new Date(value);

  const month = String(date.getMonth() + 1).padStart(2, '0');
  const day = String(date.getDate()).padStart(2, '0');

  return `${day}${symbol}${month}`;
}
// interfaces/context.ts
export interface IAppContext {
  afterSchool: IAfterSchoolState;
  setAfterSchool: Dispatch<IAfterSchoolAction>
}

// interfaces/after-school.ts
export interface IAfterSchoolType {
  id: number;
  name: string;
  value: number;
  selectedDays: string[];
}

export interface IAfterSchoolService {
  id: number;
  name: string;
  types: IAfterSchoolType[];
}

export interface IAfterSchoolState {
  type: IAfterSchoolType;
  service: IAfterSchoolService;
}

export type TAfterSchoolActionType =
  | "addSchedule" | "removeSchedule" | "addAvailableDate"
  | "selectType" | "selectPerson" | "selectDay" | "selectModality"
  | "initService" | "updateServiceTypes";

export interface IAfterSchoolAction {
  type: TAfterSchoolActionType;
  payload: {
    service?: IAfterSchoolService;
    date?: string;
    removeDate?: string;
    availableDate?: number;
    type?: IAfterSchoolType;
  };
}

export const initialTypeState: IAfterSchoolType = {
  id: 0,
  name: "",
  selectedDays: [],
  value: 0
};

export const initialServiceState: IAfterSchoolService = {
  id: 0,
  name: "",
  types: [],
};

export const initialAfterSchoolState: IAfterSchoolState = {
  type: initialTypeState,
  service: initialServiceState,
};

export const AppContext = createContext<IAppContext | undefined>(undefined);

// context/index.tsx
export const MyAppContext = ({ children }: any) => {
  const [afterSchool, setAfterSchool] = useReducer(afterSchoolReducer, initialAfterSchoolState);

  return (
    <AppContext.Provider value={{ afterSchool, setAfterSchool }
    }>
      {children}
    </AppContext.Provider>
  )
}

// context/reducer/after-school.reducer.ts
export const afterSchoolReducer = (state: IAfterSchoolState, action: IAfterSchoolAction): IAfterSchoolState => {
  const { type, payload } = action;

  switch (type) {
    case 'removeSchedule': {
      const { removeDate } = payload;

      if (!removeDate) return state;

      const updatedSelectedDays = state.type.selectedDays.filter(date => date !== removeDate);

      return {
        ...state,
        type: {
          ...state.type,
          selectedDays: [...updatedSelectedDays],
        },
      };
    };

    case "updateServiceTypes":
      console.log("updateServiceTypes type:", state.type)
      const newTypes = state.service.types.map(type =>
        (type.id === state.type.id)
          ? state.type
          : type
      );

      return {
        ...state,
        service: {
          ...state.service,
          types: newTypes
        }
      };

    case "selectType":
      if (!payload.type) return state;

      return { ...state, type: payload.type };

    case "addSchedule":
      if (!payload.date) return state;

      const newDates = payload.date;

      return {
        ...state,
        type: {
          ...state.type,
          selectedDays: [...state.type.selectedDays, newDates]
        },
      };

    default:
      return state;
  }
}

// hooks/app-context.hook.ts
export const useAppContext = () => {
  const context = useContext(AppContext);
  if (!context) {
    throw new Error('useAppContext debe ser usado dentro de MyAppContext');
  }
  return context;
};

// hooks/after-school.ts
export const useAfterSchool = () => {
  const { afterSchool: { type, service }, setAfterSchool } = useAppContext();

  const getServiceList = () => {
    const resp = GetDailyServicesResponse;

    const data: IAfterSchoolService = {
      id: resp.serviceId,
      name: resp.name,
      types: resp.services.map(val => ({
        id: val.id,
        name: val.name,
        value: val.value,
        selectedDays: [],
      }))
    }

    setAfterSchool({ type: "initService", payload: { service: data } });
  };

  const handleSelectService = (id: number) => {
    const findService = service.types.find(type => type.id === id);

    if (!findService) return;

    setAfterSchool({ type: "updateServiceTypes", payload: {} });
    setAfterSchool({ type: "selectType", payload: { type: findService } });
  }

  const handleDateSelect = (date: Date) => {
    setAfterSchool({ type: "addSchedule", payload: { date: date.toString() } });
    setAfterSchool({ type: "updateServiceTypes", payload: {} });
  };

  const handleDateRemove = (date: string) => {
    setAfterSchool({ type: "removeSchedule", payload: { removeDate: date } });
    setAfterSchool({ type: "updateServiceTypes", payload: {} });
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    getServiceList();
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("type:", type);
  }, [type]);

  return {
    selectedType: type,
    service,
    handleDateSelect,
    handleDateRemove,
    handleSelectService,
  }
}
//App.tsx
export const App3 = () => {
  const { selectedType, service, handleSelectService, handleDateSelect, handleDateRemove } = useAfterSchool();

  return (
    <main className="mainContainer" >
      <article>
        {
          service.types.map(type => (
            <div
              key={type.id}
              className={`serviceCard ${selectedType.id === type.id ? "isSelected" : ""}`}
              onClick={() => handleSelectService(type.id)}
            >
              {type.name} {type.value}

              {
                type.selectedDays.map(selectedDay => (
                  <p key={selectedDay} onClick={() => handleDateRemove(selectedDay)}> {formatDayMonth(selectedDay, "/")} </p>
                ))}
            </div>
          ))}
      </article>

      <article>
        {
          MockDates.map((day, idx) => (
            <div
              key={idx}
              onClick={() => handleDateSelect(day)}
              className="serviceCard"
            >
              {formatDayMonth(day.toString(), "/")}
            </div>
          ))}
      </article>
    </main>
  )
}

Issue :
When removing a date, the state does not update, and the useEffect hook is not triggered as expected. What could be causing this issue, and how can I ensure the state updates correctly and triggers the useEffect?
Any help or insights would be greatly appreciated!

The code you have shared is missing several types/interfaces, the reducer function is missing cases. Please [edit] to pare this down to a minimal and complete [mcve] that includes all the relevant code to be able to reproduce the issue you are asking for help with.

This is a lot of code to post, you should be able to reduce your problem to something simpler that reproduces the problem.

React may not cause re-renders and hence the useEffect does not trigger if you are executing two different actions at almost the same time on the very same object. I would recommend refactoring your codebase to perform a single action over the array instead of two consequent ones:
join your actions into one
// context/reducer/after-school.reducer.ts
export const afterSchoolReducer = (state: IAfterSchoolState, action: IAfterSchoolAction): IAfterSchoolState => {
  const { type, payload } = action;

  switch (type) {
    case 'removeSchedule': {
      const { removeDate } = payload;
    
      if (!removeDate) return state;
    
      const updatedSelectedDays = state.type.selectedDays.filter(date => date !== removeDate);
    
      const newTypes = state.service.types.map(t =>
        (t.id === state.type.id)
          ? { ...state.type, selectedDays: updatedSelectedDays }
          : t
      );

      return {
        ...state,
        type: {
          ...state.type,
          selectedDays: updatedSelectedDays,
        },
        service: {
          ...state.service,
          types: newTypes
        }
      };
    }

    default:
      return state;
  }
};

refactored hook
// hooks/after-school.ts
export const useAfterSchool = () => {
  const { afterSchool: { type }, setAfterSchool } = useAppContext();

  const handleDateRemove = (date: string) => {
    setAfterSchool({ type: "removeSchedule", payload: { removeDate: date } });
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("type:", type);
  }, [type.selectedDays]); // React will re-trigger on `selectedDays` change
}

Please also note that useEffect now relies on type.selectedDays to re-trigger.

Sir, thank you for your response.
I made the changes you mentioned and the same problem continues

Can you also provide component code so that I could reproduce it on my local and see what's going on?

yes sir.
I give you the link to the Gitlab repository. Use dev branch and App3 component. https://gitlab.com/matias_alfaro/samplate-react-app

The useEffect is triggering just fine. But the issue occurs when you add same date multiple time and using the same key for multiple list items
// In the App3 component 
{type.selectedDays.map(selectedDay => (
  <p key={selectedDay} onClick={() => handleDateRemove(selectedDay)}>{formatDayMonth(selectedDay, "/")}</p>))}

Instead
  {type.selectedDays.map((selectedDay, index) => (
 <p key={`${selectedDay}${index}`} onClick={() => handleDateRemove(selectedDay)}>{formatDayMonth(selectedDay, "/")}</p>))}

There are better ways of doing it, just pointed the root cause

try this and the error still occurs

Issues
If I've understood your code correctly then the main issues I have found in the code are:

You've duplicate state values between state.service, specifically state.service.types, and the state.type states, and you've competing actions trying to update one or the other and trying to synchronize them.
The handleDateRemove handler is called but doesn't know from which type to delete from

Solution Suggestions
More Accurate Action Types
The first suggestion I have is to type your actions more accurately. Instead of TAfterSchoolActionType which can be any action type and IAfterSchoolAction which can have any payload value, explicitly type the actions.
Old:
type TAfterSchoolActionType =
  | "addSchedule"
  | "removeSchedule"
  | "addAvailableDate"
  | "selectType"
  | "selectPerson"
  | "selectDay"
  | "selectModality"
  | "initService"
  | "updateServiceTypes";

interface IAfterSchoolAction {
  type: TAfterSchoolActionType;
  payload: {
    service?: IAfterSchoolService;
    date?: string;
    removeDate?: string;
    availableDate?: number;
    type?: number;
  };
}

New:
type IAfterSchoolAction =
  | {
      type: "initService";
      payload: {
        service: IAfterSchoolService;
      };
    }
  | {
      type: "selectType";
      payload: {
        id: number;
      };
    }
  ....
  | {
      type: "addSchedule";
      payload: {
        date: string;
      };
    }
  | {
      type: "removeSchedule";
      payload: {
        id: number;
        date: string;
      };
    };

This allows Typescript to correctly infer the action.payload type based on the action.type value.
De-duplicate the State
Instead of storing a duplicate "copy" of an entire state.service.types type object in the state, store just the selected type.id into the state.

Update the IAfterSchoolState interface:
interface IAfterSchoolState {
  selectedTypeId: number;
  service: IAfterSchoolService;
}


Update the initialAfterSchoolState value:
const initialAfterSchoolState: IAfterSchoolState = {
  selectedTypeId: 0,
  service: initialServiceState,
};



Update Handlers and Reducer Cases

Update the handlers and reducer cases to correctly handle the updated state interfaces.
const afterSchoolReducer = (
  state: IAfterSchoolState,
  action: IAfterSchoolAction
): IAfterSchoolState => {
  const { type, payload } = action;

  switch (type) {
    case "removeSchedule": {
      if (
        !state.service.types.some(
          (type) =>
            type.id === state.selectedTypeId &&
            type.selectedDays.includes(payload.date)
        )
      ) {
        // Nothing to remove, return current state
        return state;
      }

      // Remove the matching date from the selected days array of
      // the matching services type object
      return {
        ...state,
        service: {
          ...state.service,
          types: state.service.types.map((type) =>
            type.id === payload.id
              ? {
                  ...type,
                  selectedDays: type.selectedDays.filter(
                    (selectedDate) => selectedDate !== payload.date
                  ),
                }
              : type
          ),
        },
      };
    }

    ...

    case "selectType":
      // Already selected, do nothing and return current state
      if (payload.id === state.selectedTypeId) return state;

      return { ...state, selectedTypeId: payload.id };

    case "addSchedule":
      if (
        state.service.types.some(
          (type) =>
            type.id === state.selectedTypeId &&
            type.selectedDays.includes(payload.date)
        )
      ) {
        // Already added, return current state
        return state;
      }

      // Add the date to the selected days array of
      // the matching services type object
      return {
        ...state,
        service: {
          ...state.service,
          types: state.service.types.map((type) =>
            type.id === state.selectedTypeId
              ? {
                  ...type,
                  selectedDays: type.selectedDays.concat(payload.date),
                }
              : type
          ),
        },
      };

    case "initService":
      return {
        ...state,
        service: payload.service,
      };

    default:
      return state;
  }
};


Update the handlers to pass the appropriate payload values
const handleSelectService = (id: number) => {
  setAfterSchool({ type: "selectType", payload: { id } });
};

const handleDateSelect = (date: Date) => {
  setAfterSchool({ type: "addSchedule", payload: { date: date.toString() } });
};

const handleDateRemove = (id: number, date: string) => {
  setAfterSchool({ type: "removeSchedule", payload: { date, id } });
};


Update the UI to pass the appropriate values to handlers
const {
  selectedTypeId,
  service,
  handleSelectService,
  handleDateSelect,
  handleDateRemove
} = useAfterSchool();

...

<main className="mainContainer">
  <article>
    {service.types.map((type) => (
      <div
        key={type.id}
        className={`serviceCard ${
          selectedTypeId === type.id ? "isSelected" : ""
        }`}
        onClick={() => handleSelectService(type.id)}
      >
        {type.name} {type.value}
        {type.selectedDays.map((selectedDay) => (
          <p
            key={selectedDay}
            onClick={() => handleDateRemove(type.id, selectedDay)}
          >
            {formatDayMonth(selectedDay, "/")}
          </p>
        ))}
      </div>
    ))}
  </article>

  <hr />

  <article>
    {MockDates.map((day, idx) => (
      <div
        key={idx}
        onClick={() => handleDateSelect(day)}
        className="serviceCard"
      >
        {formatDayMonth(day.toString(), "/")}
      </div>
    ))}
  </article>
</main>




Here's a running CodeSandbox demo.
